# What is the wrong with onBindViewHolder method

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I use `onBindViewHolder` in my `CardAdapter`. It includes an `onClick` method of `checkedTextView`.I am trying to get these texts and put to `Arraylist(sharedP)`. But `ArrayList` only returns the last element. Where is my fault?

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CardTasarimTutucu holder, int position) {

        SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checked",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        e=sp.edit();
        sharedP= new ArrayList<>();
        word = words.get(position).getMean();
        Log.e("getMean",word);
        id= words.get(position).getId();
        str= new StringBuffer("");

        holder.rowText.setText(word);
        holder.rowText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.rowText.isChecked()) {

                    sharedP.remove(sharedP.indexOf(word));
                    flag=false;
                    holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
                    holder.rowText.setChecked(false);

                } else {

                    sharedP.add(word);
                    flag=true;
                    Log.e("deneme",word);
                    holder.rowText.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
                    holder.rowText.setChecked(true);

                }

                str.delete(0,str.length());
                for(int i=0;i<sharedP.size();i++){
                    Log.e("sharedpreference1",sharedP.get(i).toString());
                    str.append(sharedP.get(i));
                    str.append(".");

                }
                if(flag==false){
                    e.remove("str");
                    e.commit();
                }
                Log.e("size",str.toString());
                e.putString("str", str.toString());
                e.remove("set");

                e.commit();

            }

        });




    }
```

[example of checkedTextView](https://i.hizliresim.com/DOaYPz.png)

[shared preference](https://i.hizliresim.com/lQVqWk.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all `onBindViewHolder` is calling for each item in `RecyclerView` in order to display the data in each position in the view item. So it is like a loop. In your code you initialize the `sharedP` array inside `onBindViewHolder` `sharedP= new ArrayList<>();`. So for each item you pass / scroll , the array is getting initialized again and the previous item is being lost.In other words when you reach the end of your list you will have only 1 item inside your list , the last one.

Comment: So, is there an another way to get all items?